# Basic web-address validation regex?

Tags: .net, regex, validation

I am looking for a regex that validates simple website addresses, i.e.

- http://www.stackoverflow.com
- www.stackoverflow.com
- stackoverflow.com
- stack-overflow.co.it

I need it for contact details, 'Website' field, then when user click it opens IE, **it doesn't have to be strict**, I just don't want the user to enter 'I love milk' or 'google' etc.

I thought instead shrinking my mind writing my own struggling to find exception, why won't I learn from the community experience, anyone who has a good regex or a link please post.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [RFC 3986, Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), appendix B (p. 50):

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

If the URI matches this regular expression, it's well formed.  The match groups give you the various pieces, which are:

```
scheme    = $2
authority = $4
path      = $5
query     = $7
fragment  = $9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```

excerpt from http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/

---

```
 (https?://)?([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?
```

revise per suggestion, but i think people should better follow the clue and figure out the answer themselves. anyway, even copy/paste, people should know what they are doing.

Comment: That doesn't satisfy OP's requirements.  He doesn't want to force the 'http' prefix.  However drop the https?:// part of it, and it should.

Answer (score 0):

I also mentioned the RFC 3986, but it is a bit too generic, as it is made to match relative URLs as well. Obviously, in the OP case, we want absolute public URLs.

Something like `^(https?://)?(?:[\w.]+)\.(?:[\w:.]+)` seems more realistic. I deliberately exclude sites needing username/password pair, but accept port number.
This kind of expression will break when Unicode URLs will be commonplace...

[EDIT] I accepted any scheme, I should restrict more, I suppose, no need to accept ftp addresses or bzr+ssl:// ones for the exposed case...

Answer (score 0):

Validating or detecting URLs is not as straightforward as it looks. This is a blog post which digs a little deeper into this topic:

http://www.blog.activa.be/2008/10/30/ExtractingURLsNotPerfectButQuotgoodEnoughquot.aspx

and also:

https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/

Comment: Good pages.  Everyone keeps trying to reinvent the RFC.  Is it deficient?

Answer (score 0):

One option without using regex, but `address` must start with a protocol like `http://`:

```
static bool validateAddress(string address)
{
    Uri valid = null;
    return 
        address.StartsWith("http") &&
        Uri.TryCreate(address, UriKind.Absolute, out valid);
}
```